# socketfilterfw process eats 130-160% CPU while Xcode running, macbook is ready to fly

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

In the latest Xcode I systematically get dramatic slow-down by `socketfilterfw` process.
It takes my MacBook almost to fly with over than 100% CPU usage.

It can be stopped only by killing this process.

What is wrong with Xcode?

Comment: Just had the same issue! xcode 7.3, yesterday I installed el capitan. As soon as I start xcode socketfilterfw goes nuts. It doesn't download anything.

Comment: @costa, please check your Brandmauer settings for xCode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was in Brandmauer (Firewall Settings)!

My Xcode was blocked for incoming connections. Now after "allow" choice I almost have no that problem with `socketfilterfw` process eating CPU.

[image]

Comment: I had it allowing incoming connections to begin with. When I start xcode, I noticed socketfilterfw eats CPU at 140% for a minute or so, then it goes back to normal.

Comment: @SimonTillson firewall